# Google Apps Script: Why Does this Sorting Not Work?

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script

new to google apps script and trying to find the second highest value in a range. When I input a range like `[45, 101, 100, 40]` the value returned is `101`. Clearly the `sort()` isn't working as it is just returning the second value in the range. What am I missing?

```
function second_max(range) {
  if (range) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
      arr.push(range[i]);
    }
    arr.sort();
    Logger.log(arr);
    return arr[1];
  }

}
```

Comment: Is it a custom function?

Comment: yep! It is a custom function I am trying to build that I will use in google sheets to find the second highest max in a range

Comment: How are you calling the function? [Edit] your question to show a sample call from sheet. eg: `=SECOND_MAX(A1:F1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `arr.sort()` to `arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})`.

It doesn't sort because it thinks it's a string. For example,
[1, 5, 2, 100, 500, 250, 60, 55, 100000] will be sorted to [1, 100, 100000, 2, 250, 5, 500, 55, 60].

So, you'd better to implement subtraction callback function inside of sort() so that you can get the right result.

check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

- `range` is a two dimensional array - array of arrays(eg:`[[45], [101], [100], [40]]`). `arr.sort` can sort only numbers.

#### Solution(s):

You can try any of the following:

- You can easily  use inbuilt formulas like [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624) to do the same:

  ```
    =INDEX(SORTN(A1:A20,2),2)
  ```
- Pass a [`compareFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to parse the array and sort.
- [`Flat`ten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array and use Math.max

#### Snippet:

```
// Will only work for vertical rows as horizontal ranges like A1:C1 looks like [[1,2,3]]; Modify it accordingly.
function second_max(arr) {
  return arr.sort(([a],[b])=>b-a)[1][0];
}

/* Works with any 2D array*/
function second_max2(arr) {
  let flatArr = arr.flat();
  let max1 = Math.max(...flatArr);
  return Math.max(...flatArr.filter(num=>num !== max1))
}
```